# Existing property not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, selectlist

I am trying to make a dropdown box in ASP.NET, when the View is generated it gives me an error  saying Categorie_ID is not found in Model Categorie (it does exist and it's public and all). The categories and product are succesfully being loaded (I have debugged that part).

Here's what I got;

My view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = @Model.Product.Merk; @Model.Product.Type;;
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model WebshopProjectBlokC.ViewModels.ProductViewModel      
<h2>@Model.Product.Merk @Model.Product.Type wijzigen</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductWijzigenForm", "ProductBeheer"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Product.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Product.Naam)
        <div class="editor-label">Prijs</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Prijs)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Prijs)</div>
        <div class="editor-label">Maat</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Maat)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Maat)</div>
        <div class="editor-label">Merk</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Merk)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Merk)</div>
        <div class="editor-label">Type</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Type)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Type)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedID, Model.Categorien)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">URL Foto</div>
        <div class="editor-field"> 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Afbeelding)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Afbeelding)</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Wijzig" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

The controller:

```
    public ActionResult ProductWijzig(int productid)
    {
        ProductViewModel viewModel = new ProductViewModel();
        Product product = ProductdataController.GetProduct(productid);
        List<Categorie> catas = ProductdataController.HaalCategorienOp();
        viewModel.Categorien = new SelectList(catas, "Categorie_id", "Naam");
        viewModel.Product = product;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The viewmodel:

```
namespace WebshopProjectBlokC.ViewModels
{
   public class ProductViewModel
   {
       public Product Product { get; set; }
       public Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
       public SelectList Categorien { get; set; }
       public int SelectedID { get; set; }
   }
```

}

The HaalCategorienOp method;

```
    public List<Categorie> HaalCategorienOp()
    {
        List<Categorie> categorien = new List<Categorie>();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string selecteer = "select * from categorie";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selecteer, conn);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Categorie categorie = HaalCategorieUitReader(dataReader);
                categorien.Add(categorie);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Ophalen van categorien mislukt " + e);
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return categorien;
    }
```

HaalCategorieUitReader method;

```
  protected Categorie HaalCategorieUitReader(MySqlDataReader datareader)
    {
        if (!datareader.IsDBNull(0))
        {
            categorie_id = datareader.GetInt32("categorie_id");
        }
        if (!datareader.IsDBNull(1))
        {
            categorienaam = datareader.GetString("naam");
        }
        if (!datareader.IsDBNull(2))
        {
            hoofdcategorie = datareader.GetInt32("hoofdcategorie");
        }

        Categorie categorie = new Categorie{ Categorie_id = categorie_id, Hoofdcategorie = hoofdcategorie, Naam = categorienaam};

        return categorie;
    }
```

Comment: What is the structure that this method returns `HaalCategorienOp`? You have it inside `ProductWijzig`.

Comment: Its a simple method that returns a list of categories.

Comment: Can you include it in your question. The reason I'm asking is to make sure you have a property named `Categorie_id`.

Comment: New methods have been added.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, what I was asking is the entity returned by `HaalCategorienOp` and it is `Categorie`. But I read your question again and you mentioned that `Categorie_ID` does exist in `Categorie` and it's public. So that's weird, what I can tell you is to remove each field and put them one by one, do it on the view as well. That's a good way of debugging. So you can concentrate on smaller parts of your code.

Comment: Didn't even read the whole question as it is very long but make sure you compiled.

Comment: I have debugged everything. at return View(ViewModel) the entities that are given with ViewModel all contain the right values. Even at the View everything has the right value so it's all being retrieved and such. It gives me the following error still: "HttpException was unhandled by user" with: "Databinding: WebShopBlokC.Models.Categorie' does not contain a property with the name "Categorie_ID". Does this have something to do with the usage ViewModel instead of a normal Model?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to fix this. Can someone please look at it again?